# JavaScript : Iterate pushed elements in a same loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-in-loop

How to iterate pushed value as well in a same loop.

I have one `array` like,

```
var arrays = [
    "hii",
    "hello"
];
```

I iterate using `for in` with `push`,

```
for (var index in arrays) {
    arrays.push(arrays[index] + " world");
    console.log(arrays[index]);
}
console.log(arrays);
```

Output :

```
hii
hello
Array(4): 0 : "hii", 1 : "hello", 2 : "hii world", 3 : "hello world"
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/nq59yueL/20/).

Question : How do I iterate pushed element and iterate within same loop ?

Comment: `for ... in` [should not be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) to iterate over arrays. For the rest, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you might right. `for...in...` use for an object as [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: The iterator will never end if you want to iterate those pushed elements too within the iteration.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I pushed conditionally not every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: OP edited the question to include pushed elements too in the iteration

If you want to include the pushed elements during the iteration (which you claim to do conditionally to prevent infinity), you can use `for` loop with `Array.length`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {

    if (some_condition)
       arrays.push(arrays[i] + 'world'); 

}
```

The loop will always try to go up to the new length.

---

Previous answer:

The `Array.forEach` method doesn't apply the iterator to the elements those are pushed during the iteration.

```js
const arrays = [
    "hii",
    "hello"
];

arrays.forEach((e, i, a) => {
   a.push(e + ' world')

});


console.log(arrays)
```

Comment: Actually I want to iterate pushed element in same loop. Please see my edited question sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the answer.

Comment: The loop will never end if you push and iterate the new one in the iterator

Comment: Right. But I pushed conditionally.

Comment: Scenario : Want to push element conditionally and iterate it within same loop. is it possible ?
Hopefully you get me.

Comment: Yes. It is working perfectly [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/nq59yueL/50/). Thank you so much you saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like as follows

```
[...arrays,...arrays.map(a=>a+' world')]
```

Example is as follows

```js
var arrays = [
    "hii",
    "hello"
];

function appendWorld(arr){
  return [...arrays,...arrays.map(a=>a+' world')]
}

console.log(appendWorld(arrays))
```

Answer (score 2):

Map it and flatten it

```js
const arrays = [
    "hii",
    "hello"
];

let x=arrays.map(a=>[a,a+' world']).flat();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But this code does not pushes element in array.

Comment: @JaydeepMor : it does , but just in different way

Answer (score 1):

This could be the simplest answer:

```
var b=["hi",'hello'];

var arrayLength = b.length;
for(var i=0;i<arrayLength*2;i++){
   if(i < arrayLength) b.push(b[i] + " world");
   console.log(b[i]);
}
console.log(b);
```

Output:
[image]

set length to hardcoded *2 as you only want to add element once in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Have you check `console.log(b);` after complete loop ? It has unexpected pushed.

Comment: Edited the answer.Added a check inside loop

Comment: Either you didn't get me properly or something doing wrong. Please check `var b` after loop it has unexpected values.

Comment: printing b gives 4 values in array. isn't this you want ?
Edited in answer .

b = ["hi", "hello", "hi world", "hello world"];

Comment: Glad i could be of help.Can you please upvote my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a while?

```
let myArray = ["one", "two", "three"];
let i = 0;
while (myArray.lenght > i)
{
    if (anyCondition)
    {
        myArray.push('aló')
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
for (var index in arrays) {
    arrays[index] += " world";
    console.log(arrays[index]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nope ! this is not what I want. I want to `push` element in the same `array` and iterate it within same loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you want.

```
var arrays = [
    "hii",
    "hello"
];

for(var i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++){
  arrays.push(arrays[i] + " world");
  console.log(arrays[i]);
  /* This line breaks the code*/
  if(i == 10) break
}
console.log(arrays)
```

Output:

```
hii
hello
hii world
hello world
hii world world
hello world world
hii world world world
hello world world world
hii world world world world
hello world world world world
hii world world world world world
["hii", "hello", "hii world", "hello world", "hii world world", "hello world world", "hii world world world", "hello world world world", "hii world world world world", "hello world world world world", "hii world world world world world", "hello world world world world world", "hii world world world world world world"]
```

This definitely iterates through the new elements. I'm not sure if you ever want to do this, since it makes an infinite loop without the break statement.